# Could not initialize class com.tibco.as.space.impl.NativeImpl

Tags: java, tibco-ems

I was trying to connect tibco metaspacename, at highlighted line getting exception

Code:

```
  MemberDef memberDef = MemberDef.create();
  memberDef.setDiscovery(discovery);

  this.metaspace = ASCommon.getMetaspace(metaspacename); // exception on this line
  if(metaspace == null)
   this.metaspace = Metaspace.connect(metaspacename, memberDef);
```

Exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tibco.as.space.impl.NativeImpl
    at com.tibco.as.space.ASCommon.getMetaspace(ASCommon.java:173)
    at org.activespace.cache.ActiveSpaceCacheHandler.configureTibco(ActiveSpaceCacheHandler.java:111)
```

Find related to this issue on google(need to check version of jre and tibco) , both are 64 bit in my case.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to fix this issue:

1. Backup `TIBCO_HOME/bw/version_number/bin/bwengine` and `TIBCO_HOME/designer/version_number/bin/designer`.
2. After installing *TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks Plug-in for ActiveSpaces*, replace *bwengine* and *designer* with the wrapper in `ASBW_HOME/bin`.